# Display admin notice only on main dashboard page

Tags: theme-development, dashboard

I'm using following code to display a notification in the admin dashboard. I want to display only on the main dashboard page (index.php), however the following code would display on all pages in the dashboard. Is there anyway to restrict it only to the dashboard main page? Thanks.

```
function my_admin_notice() { ?>
    <div class="updated">
        <p><?php _e( 'some message', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
function my_admin_notice() { ?>
    <div class="updated">
        <p><?php _e( 'some message', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'load-index.php', 
    function(){
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
    }
);
```

where we use the `load-index.php` hook to target the *dashboard* page.

Comment: Note:  the function call back will only work in php 5.3 and above so use a function reference if you run into trouble declare a function and reference it as `'my_custom_notice_function'`

Comment: thanks for that note and to those still running on an ancient PHP < 5.3, I would suggest upgrading asap ;-) @hitautodestruct